# How can I make my "say" command delete the command message, while keeping the bot's message? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a say command, but I want it to delete my message and keep the bot's message. How would I create the object that deletes my message? Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def say(ctx, message=None):
    await ctx.send(message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a very simple approach.

You just have to add a single line of code after the line:

```
await ctx.send(message)
```

Add this line:

```
await ctx.message.delete()
```

This would delete the author's command and keep Bot's message.

So the compiled piece of code would be:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def say(ctx, message=None):
    await ctx.send(message)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `await ctx.message.delete()` to delete the author's command message.

Reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete